# Ubuntu 20.04. Attempt to delete printer driver fails from bad install

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, uninstall, canon

Went to Settings > Printers. Two drivers for Canon MX922 printer shown. Second one works. First one doesn't work. I click on settings wheel for the bad one, selected and pressed Remove Printer. Got message that says the printer has been deleted. THEN I closed the little message window. The printer REAPPEARS as "Added" (I did not click undo button). Also tried command line sudo command to delete. Printer reappeared. I just started using Linux.

Comment: Why is this a "bad install"?

Comment: Problem "solved". Printer head on my MX922 broke, so I ordered a different printer today. Checked OEM website for Linux printer driver availability first.